# E-mail body and signature different sizes

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a question about the following code that I wrote to send emails in VBA. Everything works and I have no major objections except that after generating an e-mail, the font of the message has a different size than the font of the signature. Is it possible to set it rigidly so that both the display text and the signature have the same font size?

This happens even when I set the font size in the line.

```
strbody = "<p style=font-family:arial>Hi All,<br><br>"
```

replacing it with :

```
strbody = "<p style=font-family:arial; font-size:14pt>Hi All,<br><br>"
```

Below the code:

```
Sub Report()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<p style=font-family:arial>Hi All,<br><br>" & _
"please see report.<br>"

SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
"\Microsoft\Signatures\Podpis.htm"

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
Signature = ""
End If

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@address.com"
.To = "email@address.com"
.CC = "email@address.com"
.Subject = "Report"
.HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & Signature
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.readall
ts.Close
End Function
```

Thanks a lot for any help and suggestions!

Comment: What tags do you have in `Podpis.htm` ? Is that outlook generated ?

Comment: This is the name of the file in .htm format from which the signature is drawn to the body of the message.

Comment: Yes. please show the content of the file in .htm format from which the signature is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `MsoAutoSig` class with your format

```vb
GetBoiler = Replace(ts.readall, "class=MsoAutoSig", "style=""font-family:arial; font-size:14pt""")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!